# I want to divide a string to some string

Tags: java, string

I want to divide a string to some string in android ,java.
The input is a string variable.

for example:
I have a string with 238 words,i divide to 50 words in 5 string.
1 string is 50 words
2 string is 50 words
3 string is 50 words
4 string is 50 words
5 string is 38 words.

for other examples:
1- i have a string with 370 words
2- i have a string with 510 words
3- i have a string with 858 words

Comment: so whats the problem. Don't want to use substring()?

Comment: please show how do it in example?i don,t want to divide characters i want to divide words?

Comment: Splitting a `String` is not an android problem but a Java programming problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `split(" ")` if you can assume that your words are seperated by one space each. You may need some more code to assure this assumption, e.g. by replacing multiple spaces with one or something like this.

`split` will give you an array of all your words. The method `Arrays.copyOfRange` could then become handy :D

Answer (score 0):

From the java docs:

> substring
>
> public String substring(int beginIndex)
>
> ```
> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins with the character at the specified index and extends to the end of this string.
> ```

You have to do a `myString.substring(50)` as many times as you want. If you a specific identifier in your string e.g. "," then you can do a split on the basis of that `myString.split(",")`

More importantly I suggest you to have a look at [String Class doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29)

Comment: but substring return characters, not words?! for example : my string is "hello how are you are you ok". i want return strings 1."hello how" 2. "are you" 3."are you" 4."ok"

Comment: i see it but all class for characters,you con,t help me may others can

Answer (score 0):

substring is pretty inefficient but i agree with @LostAvatar that the split method would work.
When you split the string / sentence or whatever it is you can assign each split word (provided u specify a delimeter) into a String array so you access each word using an index. Pretty simple. 
 E.g. `String sentence ="cats are evil";`
`String[] tokens = sentence.split(" ");`

 So if u want to access 'are' you use `tokens[1]`,simple as that just make sure the delimeter is correct.

To split sentences maybe you can also put them into string arrays using the split method but the delimeters this time will be fullstops then you can further break them down into words.